# Flink Aws S3 Access Issue (Intellij idea)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-flink

I am trying to read S3 from Intellij idea using Flink I have followed all the steps mentioned in several blog and website how to read S3 file in Flink.

I am unable to solve this aws credentials issue I am not sure why flink is unable to access credentials which are in core-site.xml file.

Intellij Idea env variable:-
[image]

Error:-

```
No AWS Credentials provided by BasicAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : org.apache.flink.fs.s3base.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint
```

core-site.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3.impl</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3.buffer.dir</name>
        <value>/tmp</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm</name>
        <value>AES256</value>
    </property>

    <!--<property>
        <name>fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SharedInstanceProfileCredentialsProvider</value>
    </property>-->

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
        <value>*****</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
        <value>*****</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.session.token</name>
        <value>*****</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Flink Conf:-

```
fs.hdfs.hadoopconf: /Users/FlinkStreamAndSql-master/src/main/resources/hadoop-config
```

POM:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>FlinkStreamAndSql</groupId>
    <artifactId>FlinkStreamAndSql</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- see http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin -->
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.13</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useFile>false</useFile>
                    <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
                    <!-- If you have classpath issue like NoDefClassError,... -->
                    <!-- useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar -->
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                        <include>**/*Suite.*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- "package" command plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.13.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-jdbc_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-scala_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-planner_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-scala_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
           <artifactId>flink-scala_2.11</artifactId>
           <version>1.8.1</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
           <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_2.11</artifactId>
           <version>1.8.1</version>
       </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                   <artifactId>flink-connector-kinesis_2.11</artifactId>
                   <version>1.8.0</version>
                   <scope>system</scope>
                   <systemPath>${project.basedir}/Jars/flink-connector-kinesis_2.11-1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                   <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.11_2.11</artifactId>
                   <version>1.8.1</version>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                   <artifactId>amazon-kinesis-client</artifactId>
                   <version>1.8.8</version>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                   <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kinesis</artifactId>
                   <version>1.11.579</version>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                   <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                   <version>1.2.2</version>
               </dependency>
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                   <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                   <version>2.1</version>
               </dependency>

               <dependency>
                   <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
                   <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
                   <version>1.4</version>
               </dependency>

               <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamodb-streams-kinesis-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamodb-streams-kinesis-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.579</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- For Parquet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-hadoop-compatibility_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
            <artifactId>parquet-avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-twitter_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4-hadoop1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-filesystem_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
            <artifactId>json4s-jackson_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.500</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-shaded-hadoop2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-s3-fs-hadoop</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

My code:-

```
package com.aws.examples.s3

import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.Types
import org.apache.flink.api.java.{DataSet, ExecutionEnvironment}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.config.{AWSConfigConstants, ConsumerConfigConstants}
import org.apache.flink.table.api.{Table, TableEnvironment}
import org.apache.flink.table.api.java.BatchTableEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.table.sources.CsvTableSource

import java.util.Properties

object Batch {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val env: ExecutionEnvironment =
      ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val tableEnv: BatchTableEnvironment =
      TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env)
    /* create table from csv */

    val tableSrc = CsvTableSource
      .builder()
      .path("s3a://bucket/avg.txt")
      .fieldDelimiter(",")
      .field("date", Types.STRING)
      .field("month", Types.STRING)
      .field("category", Types.STRING)
      .field("product", Types.STRING)
      .field("profit", Types.INT)
      .build()

    tableEnv.registerTableSource("CatalogTable", tableSrc)

    val catalog: Table = tableEnv.scan("CatalogTable")
    /* querying with Table API */

    val order20: Table = catalog
      .filter(" category === 'Category5'")
      .groupBy("month")
      .select("month, profit.sum as sum")
      .orderBy("sum")

    val order20Set: DataSet[Row1] = tableEnv.toDataSet(order20, classOf[Row1])

    order20Set.writeAsText("src/main/resources/table1/table1")

    //tableEnv.toAppendStream(order20, classOf[Row]).writeAsText("/home/jivesh/table")
    env.execute("State")

  }

  class Row1 {

    var month: String = _

    var sum: java.lang.Integer = _

    override def toString(): String = month + "," + sum

  }

}
```

I also tried with flink configuration and create a local env , not sure why flink still unable to pick the credentials.

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain
import org.apache.flink.configuration.ConfigConstants
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.Types
import org.apache.flink.table.api.java.BatchTableEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.table.api.Table
import org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.table.sources.CsvTableSource
import org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet
import org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.config.{AWSConfigConstants, ConsumerConfigConstants}

    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "")
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8099")
    System.setProperty("https.noproxyHosts","")
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "ashproxy.kdc.capitalone.com")
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8099")
    System.setProperty("http.noproxyHosts","")
    System.setProperty("AWS_PROFILE", "default")
    System.setProperty("AWS_DEFAULT_REGION", "us-east-1")
    System.setProperty("ACCESS_KEY", "")
    System.setProperty("SECRET_KEY", "")

    // Get AWS credentials
    val credentialsProvider = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain
    val credentials = credentialsProvider.getCredentials

    import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration
    import org.apache.flink.configuration.ConfigurationUtils
    val config = new Configuration
    config.setString("FLINK_CONF_DIR","/Users/src/main/resources/flink-config")
    config.setString("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
    config.setString("fs.s3.buffer.dir", "/tmp")
    config.setString("fs.s3a.access.key", "")
    config.setString("fs.s3a.secret.key", "")
    config.setString("fs.s3a.session.token","")
    config.setString("fs.s3a.proxy.host", "")
    config.setString("fs.s3a.proxy.port", "8099")
    config.setString("fs.s3a.proxy.username", "")
    config.setString("fs.s3a.proxy.password", "")
    config.setString(ConfigConstants.ENV_FLINK_CONF_DIR,"/Users/src/main/resources/flink-config/flink-conf.yaml")
    config.setString(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_REGION, "us-east-1")
    config.setString(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, credentials.getAWSAccessKeyId)
    config.setString(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, credentials.getAWSSecretKey)

    val env: ExecutionEnvironment = ExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(config)
    val tableEnv: BatchTableEnvironment = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env)

        val tableSrc = CsvTableSource
      .builder()
      .path("s3a://flink-poc/flink-csv-input/")
      .fieldDelimiter(",")
      .field("date", Types.STRING)
      .field("month", Types.STRING)
      .field("category", Types.STRING)
      .field("product", Types.STRING)
      .field("profit", Types.INT)
      .build()
      
    tableEnv.registerTableSource("CatalogTable", tableSrc)
```

Kinesis code is working though I am able to connect kinesis but not S3.

```
import java.util.Properties
import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain
import com.aws.examples.kinesis.consumer.TransactionExampleNotWorking.TransactionJsonClass
import com.google.gson.Gson
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
import org.apache.flink.types.Row
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{DataStream, StreamExecutionEnvironment}
import org.apache.flink.table.api.scala.StreamTableEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.FlinkKinesisConsumer
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.config.{AWSConfigConstants, ConsumerConfigConstants}
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.table.api.scala._
import java.sql.{DriverManager, Time}
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.{TypeInformation, Types}
import org.apache.flink.core.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.flink.table.sources.CsvTableSource

    // set up the streaming execution environment
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    //env.enableCheckpointing(10000)

    val tEnv: StreamTableEnvironment = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)

    // Get AWS credentials
    val credentialsProvider = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain
    val credentials = credentialsProvider.getCredentials

    // Configure Flink Kinesis consumer
    val consumerConfig = new Properties
    consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_REGION, "us-east-1")
    consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, credentials.getAWSAccessKeyId)
    consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, credentials.getAWSSecretKey)
    consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfigConstants.STREAM_INITIAL_POSITION, "TRIM_HORIZON")
    consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER, "PROFILE")
    consumerConfig.put("https.proxyHost", "ashproxy.kdc.com")
    consumerConfig.put("https.proxyPort", "8099")
    consumerConfig.put("https.noproxyHosts","127.0.0.1")
    consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_PROFILE_NAME, "default")

    // Create Kinesis stream
    val kinesis =
      env.addSource(new FlinkKinesisConsumer("transactions", new SimpleStringSchema(), consumerConfig))
```

Thanks
Sri

Comment: Are You sure flink can access the `core-site.xml` ? I was getting this error when no keys were provided or if `core-site.xml` was missing. I don't think Flink is logging anything about that, but You can try to change it, so that it's not valid XML file, Flink should then throw an exception after You start execution of the job.

Generally, I can see there is a lot of dependencies in `pom.xml` that are not needed for this specific job but may cause various clashes, I would start with cleaning up the pom.xml so that it only contains necessary deps.

Comment: @DominikWosiński I even tried creating a local flink env with my configs same error check my last code in the post

Comment: Interestingly, when I was using flink to read files from s3, I've never been able to pass AWS credentials neither via System properties nor via the Flink Config, I always had to fall back to `core-site.xml`, that's why I suggested checking if Flink can access it :)

Comment: @DominikWosiński my code which reads kinesis work ok on my home pc accessing my personal aws account but when I try the same code at work accessing work aws account it fails , at my work the aws account has extra parameter called aws_session_token

Comment: @DominikWosiński Kinesis error went away , but s3 is still failing I have edited my question and added working kinesis part